# JavaScript: Recuperar texto de um Option

Tags: javascript

Onde está o erro neste código abaixo que só está retornando a sigla do estado?

```js
window.onload=function(){
 var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
 var cmdEstados = form.Estados;
 
 cmdEstados.onchange=function(){
  alert("Sigla: " + this.value + " Estado: " + this.firstChild.nodeValue);
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Página Teste</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <body>
  <form>   
   <SELECT name="Estados">
    <OPTION value=''>--Selecione--</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='CE'>Ceará</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='DF'>Distrito Federal</OPTION>    
    <OPTION value='PB'>Paraíba</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='PE'>Pernambuco</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='SP'>São Paulo</OPTION>
   </SELECT>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro usares assim:

```
var sigla = this.value;
var estado = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
alert("Sigla: " + sigla + " Estado: " + estado);
```

desse modo tens acesso ao `value` da option escolhida, e também ao `innerHTML` dessa option, apesar do caminho ter de ser `var estado = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML`

Quando usas `.firstChild` isso vai selecionar um `text node` sem `nodeValue`. Experimenta `document.querySelector('select').firstChild` e vai-te dar um node no console. Se fizeres `document.querySelector('select').firstChild.nodeValue` vai dar vazio.

```js
window.onload=function(){
 var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
 var cmdEstados = form.Estados;
 
 cmdEstados.onchange=function(){
        var sigla = this.value;
        var estado = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  alert("Sigla: " + sigla + " Estado: " + estado);
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Página Teste</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <body>
  <form>   
   <SELECT name="Estados">
    <OPTION value=''>--Selecione--</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='CE'>Ceará</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='DF'>Distrito Federal</OPTION>    
    <OPTION value='PB'>Paraíba</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='PE'>Pernambuco</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='SP'>São Paulo</OPTION>
   </SELECT>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Entendi agora o meu erro. Obrigada pela ajuda e pela explicação Sérgio!

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

Utilizando JS Puro.

```js
window.onload=function(){
 var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
 var cmdEstados = form.Estados;
 
 cmdEstados.onchange=function(){
  alert("Sigla: " + this.value + " Estado: " + this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Página Teste</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <body>
  <form>   
   <SELECT name="Estados">
    <OPTION value=''>--Selecione--</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='CE'>Ceará</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='DF'>Distrito Federal</OPTION>    
    <OPTION value='PB'>Paraíba</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='PE'>Pernambuco</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='SP'>São Paulo</OPTION>
   </SELECT>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigada Paulo, deu certo!

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de:

```
this.firstChild.nodeValue
```

Escreva:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML
```

O código ficará assim:

```js
window.onload=function(){
 var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
 var cmdEstados = form.Estados;
 
 cmdEstados.onchange=function(){
  alert("Sigla: " + this.value + " Estado: " + this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Página Teste</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <body>
  <form>   
   <SELECT name="Estados">
    <OPTION value=''>--Selecione--</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='CE'>Ceará</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='DF'>Distrito Federal</OPTION>    
    <OPTION value='PB'>Paraíba</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='PE'>Pernambuco</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='SP'>São Paulo</OPTION>
   </SELECT>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigada Vaati!